# Microsoft sql server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

Имеет Microsoft sql server 2016,Management studio 17.0 RC3.
Не могу открыт management studio 17.0 RC3, выдает ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Началась данная ошибка после установке Visual studio 2017.
Так же есть подобная конфигурации на другом компьютере, там все хорошо работает после обновления Management studio 16.3 до версии 17.0 RC3.

Пробовал переустановить sql server,management studio, так же пробовал ставить новую версию "SQL Server vNext".

Пробовал так же более старые версии мне это не помогло.
Может кто подскажет как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было переустановить "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (изолированная)"